# Strange roots of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Where do the strange roots of an equation come from?

Like this case:

$$x - 5 = 2$$
$$(x-5)(x+1) = 2(x+1)$$
$$x^2-4x-5=2x+2$$
$$x^2-6x-7=0$$
$$x^2-7x+x-7=0$$
$$x^2+x-7x-7=0$$
$$x(x+1)-7(x+1)=0$$
$$(x-7)(x+1)=0$$
$x = 7$ or $x = -1$

Comment: Here: $$(x-5)(x+1) = 2(x+1)$$

Comment: You cannot multiply by $\,x+1\,$ without first establishing that $\,x+1\ne0 \iff x \ne -1\,$.

Comment: @dxiv So it just came about because of that fact?

Comment: @Artures Yes. If you multiply the two sides of an equation by $0$ you always get equality $0=0$. If you multiply the two sides of the equation by $f(x)$ any root of $f(x)=0$ becomes a root of the new equation obtained after multiplication. In your case, multiplying by $x+1$ introduces the extraneous root $x=-1$.

Comment: Cf. [extraneous solution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You introduced the "strange" root!

$$(x-5-2) = 0$$
$$(x-7) = 0$$
$$(x-7)(x+1) = 0$$
$$\textit{etc.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the equation with $(x+1)$ on both sides was really absurd.

If you multiply an equation with a variable term, you may gain some roots and may lose some of them by dividing.

Since $0$ multiply by any number is $0$, you are changing the given equation with another one. You are just creating a different equation from existing one .

**For example:-**
Let's say $ x^2 = x$

If we divide both sides with $x$ we will get $x=1$

Here, we missed a solution which was $0$.

And since $x^2=x$ doesn't implies that $x$ is only equal to $1$, our step of division was wrong!

And if we multiply both sides of the equation $x=1$ with $x$, we will get $x^2=x$, here we have created another solution $0$. Both equations are different from each other and our step of multiplication was wrong.

You can also visit [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359730/when-are-we-permitted-to-multiply-or-divide-both-sides-of-an-equation-by-a-varia) for more details.